# Difference between MYSQL 5.5.50 and 5.7.13

Tags: php, mysql

Do you think the difference beween two version of myql DB, 5.5.5 and 5.7.13  can produce this error ?

When I install by BD on unbutu (5.7.13) with no data and my server debian with mysql 5.5.5. I have this error

[28-Aug-2016 15:44:24 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /var/www/clients/..../boutique/includes/Sites/CategoriesAdmin.php on line 576

After investigation, when I create a categories (for example) on 5.7.13, I have my id incremented but with 5.5.5, the categories is not incremented and stay at 0

My DB is created since 5.7.13. Could be a pb of incompability on that when I install my sofware on mysql 5.5.5 ?

Comment: Sounds more like 5.7.13 is taking up too much memory in your container and you don't have enough room to run php anymore.

Answer (score 0):

That's a PHP problem, (and maybe a mysql too, but definitely PHP to start with) you need to increase the `memory_limit` in your `php.ini` settings file, note that there are two, one for web server, and one for CLI, using `phpinfo();`.

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 1280M
```

After that, your script might finish well, and you can start debugging mysql settings. On that respect I have faced many issues related to `sql-mode=""` setting, due to differences in default standard behavior from 5.5 and 5.7.